# Cocoapods unable to find Xcode project

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoapods

I have been calling pod install for the same pod file for almost a year. Recently I created a new user account on my computer and moved all my project files. I updated the pod file to reflect the new path to the project and tried calling pod install but it fails with "Unable to find the Xcode project ... for the target ...". This makes no sense - I have double checked everything, so am wondering if there is a cache somewhere that is holding an old link. Has anyone else hit this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you Podfile target is euqal to projectName , if you projectName is "TestProject" you podfile should like this

`target 'TestProject' do
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'Masonry'
end`

Comment: The target is equal to the project name

Comment: one project can have several targets. Open the project ,In projcet setting,you can see all targets,  is there have one match the podfile target

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but as I said in my question, nothing has changed other than the location of the project.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do one thing. Delete `.xcworkspace` and created new `.xcworkspace` by pod install using terminal. This will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed my Mac and there is a problem with the file path. So please make sure your path is directed to your file system